# Why static files are not loading? | Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I'm trying to load static files, but it's showing following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/user/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) - home:25
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/user/style.css 404 (Not Found) - home:25
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/logo.png 404 (Not Found) - home:149
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/logo.png 404 (Not Found) - home:1
```

[image: Click here to see error image.]

**MY CODE:**

-ADMIN

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Welcome.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('Authentication.urls')),
    path('ad/', include('Ads.urls')),
    path('user/', include('UserDashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', include('AdminDashboard.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

- APPS

**template**

```
<link href="{% static 'css/user/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Dirs Structure**

[image: Click here to Project Directory Structure Image]

**CODE EXPLANATION**

- Simply added static files in the root dir and tried to import them in template but css files are not loading
- But some media files are successfully loaded like this media `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" />`.
- Also in dir structure, we can see img and css folder at same place in static folder and images from image folder are loaded but css from css folder does not.

Comment: Did you remember to {% load static %} in your template?

Answer (score 2):

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'assets']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

add the following codes to your settings.py

be sure you have assets directory with the files you need . create static and media folder in your root directory .

if you are using DEBUG=True , then you don't need to set anything about static files in your main urls.py . so you can exclude these lines . they are used for DEBUG=False

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

and in the end run

python manage.py collectstatic

command and you are all set .

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: can you check your debug value in settings.py ? is it set to True?

Comment: oh . i just noticed you have two /admin urls in urls.py . remove the last one if you want to use django admin

Comment: `DEBUG = True`, this is set in django settings.

Comment: also removing from admin urls changes nothing

Comment: I would recommend to double check your templates as well if `{% load static %}` is included

Comment: well there is no other way to do this. and not so challenging . i edit my answer and give a total guide about how to set static files and look which part u are missing

Comment: still not working

Comment: where did you check it ? on django admin?

Comment: I checked in django admin settings.py

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and managed to fix it with these lines in settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
#
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#
]


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#for this, create the 'statics_files' directory in your project
#folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')]

#when deploying, specify the static_root setting as below
#for example, if you are deploying to a VPS root folder and your 
#application is call 'myproject'
STATIC_ROOT = '/root/myproject/static/'
#after specifying the STATIC_ROOT setting, you run the
#'collectstatic' command (*python manage.py collectstatic*)
#this will collect static files to your static root in a new 
#folder called 'static' and everything will work as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

`Settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_collect")
```

`urls.py`

```
+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Add these after closing bracket of urlpatterns.

Fire this command
`python manage.py collectstatic`

Before all this setup create a static folder inside your project folder. Hope this works for you

Comment: done as you said but nothing changed.

Comment: `<link href="{% static 'css/user/style.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">`try these. Because it seems like you have given a space. You can check in the browser Network > CSS whether your style.css is is getting 200 or other error.

Comment: tried, but same results.

Comment: Okay. Is there two folder of static created in your project? If yes, then check out in the browser whether you are able to get the style.css, is it showing 200 or 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation on static images files. After checking your settings.py

Your configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

STATIC ROOT  is only necessary when you are deploying your website.

**SOLUTION**

In the django 4.1 version, If you are in development you can simply use the below in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS= [
    BASE_DIR / 'static', 
]
```

Here, under *STATCTICFILES_DIRS, 'static'* is your folder name in which you have saved types of static files.

**NOTE** -  double check on {%load static%} in your template.

Hope this helps!